# Erro ao tentar definir o valor de uma propriedade da classe

Tags: python

Eu sou iniciante em Python e estou tentando. Estou tentando entender as classes, criando algumas instâncias, mas eu recebo um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module> 
    f1.name = "Jose"
  File "main.py", line 19, in set_name
    self.name = n
  File "main.py", line 19, in set_name
    self.name = n
  File "main.py", line 19, in set_name
    self.name = n
  [Previous line repeated 495 more times]
  File "main.py", line 18, in set_name
    if self.checkInvalidChars(n) == True:
  File "main.py", line 6, in checkInvalidChars
```

**Meu código:**

```
    class Employee(): 
      def __init__(self):
        self._name = ""

      def checkInvalidChars(self, string):
        _invalid = str.split("! @ # $ % ¨ & * ( ) - + = [ { ? / ° < > , : ; | \ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ª ")
        for j in list(string):
          if (j in _invalid == True) and (isinstance(string, str) == False):
            return False
          return True
      def get_name(self):
        if self._name != "":
          return self.name
        else:
          print("The name is not registred")

      def set_name(self, n):
        if self.checkInvalidChars(n) == True:
          self.name = n

      name = property(fget = get_name, fset = set_name)

    f1 = Employee()
    f1.name = "Jose"

    print(f1.name)
```

Comment: I suggest you read the community guidelines for doing a good! **Questions in English** you should ask in the community where your **native language is in stackoverflow**!

Comment: Como assim cara?? Tá dando um input de José ali e vem me enganar com inglês? Traduz aí que a gente te ajuda.

Comment: Você está fazendo `self.name = n` dentro de `set_name`, que é o *setter* do nome; ao fazer isso você cria um loop infinito. Não deveria ser `self._name = n`?

Answer (score 0):

Você está definindo recursividade infinita nos dois métodos da sua propriedade.

```
def get_name(self):
  if self._name != "":
    return self.name
  else:
    print("The name is not registred")
```

Você fez `return self.name`, mas `self.name` é uma propriedade que você definiu por:

```
name = property(fget = get_name, fset = set_name)
```

Ou seja, o valor retornado em `return self.name` será o valor retornado por `get_name`, mas isso está sendo executado dentro do próprio `get_name`, o que acaba gerando uma recursividade infinita. Dentro dos métodos *getter*, *setter* e *deleter* de uma propriedade você não pode trabalhar com a própria propriedade; ao invés disso você trabalhará direto sobre o atributo que é utilizado pela mesma, neste caso o `self._name`.

Então o correto seria:

```
def get_name(self):
  if self._name != "":
    return self._name
  else:
    print("The name is not registred")
```

O mesmo acontece com o *setter* quando faz `self.name = n`, chamando o próprio *setter*; então:

```
def set_name(self, n):
  if self.checkInvalidChars(n) == True:
    self._name = n
```